# Has the rewarded ad been watched in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, admob

I use Firebase AdMob in my React Native application and there is a rewarded ad unit that should be shown when the user hits the special button. This button component and the function that calls ad banner are implemented in separate files. So, my function need to return a value that shows if the user has watched the full ad and got a reward or not. But I can't figure out how to return value after `rewarded.onAdEvent` event has ended with a `type === RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD`. There are an example of my function that calls the ad and my button component:

**Ads.js fragment**

```
const showRewarded = () => {
    const rewarded = RewardedAd.createForAdRequest(UNIT_ID, {
      requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: false,
    });
    const eventListener = rewarded.onAdEvent((type, error, reward) => {
      if(type === RewardedAdEventType.LOADED) {
        rewarded.show();
      }
      if(type === RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD) {
        return reward;
      }
      // The reward should be null if user skiped the ad
      return null; 
    }); 
    rewarded.load();
    // Wait for event completion
  }
```

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';;
import { Ads } from '../components';

class MyButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  showAd() {
    // Wait while user has not been get a reward (or skiped the ad)
    const reward = Ads.showRewarded();
    console.log(`The reward is ${reward}`);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.showAd()}>
        <Text>Show Ad to get a reward</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default MyButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a better solution, but I've done it using simple `setTimeout` function while the ad unit has not been loaded. It looks like this:

```
const showRewarded = async () => {
    const rewarded = RewardedAd.createForAdRequest(UNIT_ID, {
      requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: false
    });
    var loaded = false;
    var gotReward = false;
    const eventListener = rewarded.onAdEvent((type, error, reward) => {
      if(type === RewardedAdEventType.LOADED) {
        rewarded.show();
        loaded = true;
      }
      else if(type === RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD) {
        gotReward = true;
      }
      else if(error) {
        console.warn(error);
      }
    }); 
    rewarded.load();
    while(!loaded) {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
    return gotReward;
  }
```

This function return `gotReward` only after the ad was closed. If the user watched all the ad it is true, if he has skipped this value is false.